# keyboard don't appear with facebook login

Tags: ios4, sharekit

I have a problem with ShareKit.

I'm trying to post image and text to facebook, without using the share actionsheet; I use a bar button item; the associated action is

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:reportImageView.image text:reportComment title:reportType];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

The facebook login page appears but when I touch the username or password field to insert my credentials, the iphone keyboard don't appear.

Comment: I know that is the First responder, but i have two versions and in one works perfect, but in the other not.Anyone with luck?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It really was de UIResponder. I just  use [self resignFirstResponder] in the main view and become the first responder when it need it. This only happens in IOS4, in IOS5 this doesnt care.